# Can I remove a part of a string/text with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a big doubt about Elasticsearch and it's functions

I have a field called requestparam which contatins info like this:

?q=%22art%C3%ADculo%201915%22&pagina=1&indice=tesis&extractos=120&filtros=un
defined&size=10

It's a query string, and I want to know if there's a way to query or to split a string like in this example:

?q=%22art%C3%ADculo%201915%22

So whenever it founds the substring "&pagina" it removes the rest of the string.
Is that possible with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to do that. Elasticsearch uses the query parameters for searching, filtering, pagination... .Elasticsearch will not ignore the parameters unless you create a build of ES by disabling it in Source code.